# Adobe Air Netconnection.call (remote method in dot type syntax interrupted by dot in folder name)how to escape dot in folder name?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, mobile, air, connection

I have an As3 Netconnection with a .call to a remote server that is holding my .cfc server file. The Netconnection call is in dot syntax. example - userService.call(/.jaguar.com.wwwroot.HC.remoteLogin.remoteLogin

I need to escape the (.) in jaguar.com(which is a root folder) so it doesn't confuse the dot syntax call

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... you are on the wrong track here, misunderstanding what dot syntax is and obviously not reading the docs: [NetConnection:Call()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetConnection.html#call%28%29)

Take a look at the code below ([from this site](http://etutorials.org/Macromedia/Fash+remoting.+the+definitive+guide/Part+III+Advanced+Flash+Remoting/Chapter+15.+Flash+Remoting+API/NetConnection.call/) – tutotial on Flash Remoting is worth checking out).

```
// Create a responder object
var myResult = new Object( );
// Create an onResult( ) method to handle results from the call to the remote method
myResult.onResult = function (result) {
  display_txt.text = result;
};

// Create the connection
var my_conn = new NetConnection( );
// Attach a URL for the gateway
my_conn.connect("http://127.0.0.1/flashservices/gateway");
// Call the remote method
my_conn.call("com.oreilly.frdg.HelloUser.sayHello", myResult, firstname_txt.text);
// Nullify the connection
my_conn.close( );
```

Comment: Problem: 
first connection as - userService.call("/.HC.remoteLogin.remoteLogin",responder,parameters);    (successful)

Which is read like this  /(root).HC(folder).remotelogin(.cfc file).remoteLogin(function call in the .cfc) 

But my Hosting changed my setup and add folders to userService.call("/.jaguar.com.wwwroot.HC.remoteLogin.remoteLogin",responder,parameters);  (not successful)

Which now read like this /(root).jaguar.com(folder).wwwroot(folder).HC(folder).remoteLogin(.cfc file).remoteLogin(function call in the .cfc)

How to escape  (.)com in folder name? So there is no confusion reading

Comment: Asked the hosting to just get rid of the . or the .com in the jaguar.com(folder name) so it would just be either jaguarcom or just plain jaguar but they said no. I need to escape the dot in dot com... I believe server is reading it wrong because the . in jaguar.com is not a seperator its just part of the name. THANK YOU FOR ANSWERING SO QUICKLY AND FOR THE CORRECTIONS.